# UICollectionView resizing cells upon frame change

Tags: uicollectionview, size, cell, frame

I have a collectionview. I set the cell size based on the collectionview width.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat ratio = 200.0/280.0; // w/h fixed ratio hardcode ftw!
    CGFloat cellWidth = (collectionView.frame.size.width-50)/4.0;
    CGFloat cellHeight = cellWidth / ratio;

    CGSize cellSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight);

    return cellSize;
}
```

The cells are showing nicely. But when I press a button (in the toolbar), I change this collectionview frame to bigger size. But, the width of cells remain as they are.

I don't want to call reloadData since that is reloading the whole data. How to make collectionview call this delegate again without reloadtable?

Comment: Anybody can help?

Comment: ever solved this?

Comment: Yup I solved it. But I can't remember the solution. Also I have left that job already.